# Python Web Scraping: Within href read only those values that have "http" in it

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage just for learning. In that webpage there are multiple "a" tags. consider the below code

```
<a href='\abc\def\jkl'> Something </a>
<a href ='http://www.google.com'> Something</a>
```

Now i want to read only those href attributes in which there is http.
My Current code is

```
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print link.get("href")
```

I would like to change it to read only "http" links.

Answer (score 2):

Can do it with regex like this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = """<a href="\abc\def\jkl">Something</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">something</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(res)
print soup.find_all('a', {'href' : re.compile('^http:.*')})
```

Output:

```
[<a href="http://www.google.com">something</a>]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the "starts with" [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
print([a["href"] for a in soup.select('a[href^=http]')])
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: res = """
   ...: <a href="\abc\def\jkl">Something</a>
   ...: <a href="http://www.google.com">something</a>
   ...: """

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")

In [4]: print([a["href"] for a in soup.select('a[href^=http]')])
[u'http://www.google.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run this simple test to see if the link contains the string `http`.  One extra line is required in your code to do this:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'http' in link.get('href'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if 'http' in link['href']:       
        print link['href']
```

Here link['href'] will get all text within href tag.